# Opening app from browser and redirect back to the same browser

Tags: android, oauth

For our product we want to use a feature where the user opens a specific link and our app opens. The user does some stuff and should be redirected back to the same browser.

Is there a way that I can guarantee that the same browser is used? As the user has a session in that specific browser.

so:

webbrowser --> app --> webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is sufficient but if the user behaviour is that he should only interact with your app (and nothing else on the phone) in between the browser visits you should be able to call finish(); on your activity.

From the documentation:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.
>   The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult()

\ bob

Comment: I don't think that's sufficient, as I want the browser to redirect back to another url.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible, unfortunately.